Flat serialization of single-value Java records used as strong types with Gson v2.11.0
Introduction
I am currently developing a REST client in Java v21 and got the foundation basically working.
In my project the Immutables and Gson library are currently used. Both libraries integrate pretty well together. I use these libraries to model and (un)marshal JSON payloads for the HTTP request sent from the client and HTTP responses sent from the server. By doing this I have the advantage of strongly typed (i.e. primitives and strings are always wrapped by a type) Data Transfer Objects (DTO), as well as automatic (de)serialization without the need to write any custom source code.
The more interfaces with annotations from the "Immutables" library I get, the more I think that "Immutables" is maybe not worth using. The main reasons for this are:

Nesting types with "Immutables" violates the Principle of Least Suprise (see https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/1518).
"Immutables" relies on code generation that introduces problems in an IDE when refactoring the interface types that are used for code generation.
Potential bugs due to the complexity of the "Immutables" library.

Since Java v14 record types exist in the language. I'm currently considering to replace all "Immutable" types in my project with Java record types. The Strong Type aspect isn't a big deal and can be realized as follows:
record Id(int value) {}

(De)serialization of such strong types with Gson is a "bit" more complicated , though. Sadly, Gson does not seem to provide a feature such as the @JsonValue annotation of Jackson. @JsonValue of Jackson allows to specify a single method the library will use to serialize the entire instance of a type.
Instead, Gson seems to require a TypeAdapter and a TypeAdapterFactory, in order to customize the conversion to and from JSON.
I've implemented a proof-of-concept (PoC) today and would be very happy if someone could give me some feedback.
Source Code
I've put the necessary source code into one Main.java file to provide a SSCCE.
package florianwolters;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

final class StrongRecordTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(@NotNull final Gson gson, @NotNull final TypeToken<T> type) {
        final var rawType = type.getRawType();

        if (!rawType.isRecord()
                || 1 != rawType.getRecordComponents().length
                || !"value".equals(rawType.getRecordComponents()[0].getName())) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            final var method = rawType.getMethod("value");
            final var nativeType = method.getReturnType();
            return (TypeAdapter<T>)
                    new StrongRecordTypeAdapter<>(gson.getAdapter(nativeType), (Class<? extends Record>) rawType);
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

final class StrongRecordTypeAdapter<StrongRecord> extends TypeAdapter<StrongRecord> {
    public StrongRecordTypeAdapter(
            final TypeAdapter<StrongRecord> valueAdapter, @NotNull final Class<? extends Record> clazz) {
        this.valueAdapter = valueAdapter;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull final JsonWriter out, @NotNull final StrongRecord value) throws IOException {
        if (null == value) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }

        try {
            final var method = this.clazz.getMethod("value");
            final var nativeValueAsObject = method.invoke(value);
            // TODO(2024-06-06 by wolters): Imo, `nativeValueAsObject` should be casted to the native type, which
            // seems to be impossible, due to type erasure. I do wonder why it seems to work as it is now.
            // Is this code safe?
            //              final var nativeType = method.getReturnType();
            //              final var nativeValue = nativeType.cast(nativeValueAsObject);
            valueAdapter.write(out, (StrongRecord) nativeValueAsObject);
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public StrongRecord read(@NotNull final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final var value = valueAdapter.read(in);

        try {
            final var constructors = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();

            if (1 != constructors.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "The class %s does not provide a constructor".formatted(this.clazz.getName()));
            }

            return (StrongRecord) constructors[0].newInstance(value);
        } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (final InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private final TypeAdapter<StrongRecord> valueAdapter;

    @NotNull
    private final Class<? extends Record> clazz;
}

record Person(@NotNull Person.Name name, @NotNull Person.Address address, @NotNull List<Person> relatives) {
    public record Name(@NotNull Person.Name.First first, @NotNull Person.Name.Last last) {
        public record First(@NotNull String value) {}

        public record Last(@NotNull String value) {}
    }

    public record Address(@NotNull Address.Street street) {
        public record Street(@NotNull String value) {}
    }
}

final class Main {
    public static void main(@NotNull final String[] args) {
        final var gson = createGson();

        final var jane = new Person(
                new Person.Name(new Person.Name.First("Jane"), new Person.Name.Last("Doe")),
                new Person.Address(new Person.Address.Street("Musterstraße")),
                List.of());

        final var name = new Person.Name(new Person.Name.First("John"), new Person.Name.Last("Doe"));
        final var address = new Person.Address(new Person.Address.Street("Evergreen Terrace"));
        final var relatives = List.of(jane);
        final var person = new Person(name, address, relatives);

        System.out.println(person);

        final var json = gson.toJson(person, Person.class);
        System.out.println(json);

        final var back = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
        System.out.println(back);
    }

    @NotNull
    private static Gson createGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new StrongRecordTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();
    }
}

Program Output
Person[name=Name[first=First[value=John], last=Last[value=Doe]], address=Address[street=Street[value=Evergreen Terrace]], relatives=[Person[name=Name[first=First[value=Jane], last=Last[value=Doe]], ddress=Address[street=Street[value=Musterstraße]], relatives=[]]]]
{
  "name": {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe"
  },
  "address": {
    "street": "Evergreen Terrace"
  },
  "relatives": [
    {
      "name": {
        "first": "Jane",
        "last": "Doe"
      },
      "address": {
        "street": "Musterstraße"
      },
      "relatives": []
    }
  ]
}
Person[name=Name[first=First[value=John], last=Last[value=Doe]], address=Address[street=Street[value=Evergreen Terrace]], relatives=[Person[name=Name[first=First[value=Jane], last=Last[value=Doe]], address=Address[street=Street[value=Musterstraße]], relatives=[]]]]

Questions

Is this basically the correct/appropriate approach to register and implement type conversion using Gson?

Regarding the single TODO in the source code above:

Can someone explain to me, why the serialization works, even if the record type is passed to valueAdapter?
Imo, it would be "correct" to pass the native type (wrapped by the record type) to valueAdapter, but I do not know how (even if) this is possible using Java reflection?


Do you identify any issues regarding this (imo, much simpler approach) in contrast to the "Immutables" library if using Gson?
Yes, I do not get any builders "for free". But for that I could add the RecordBuilder library that allows to generate builders for Java records using the @RecordBuilder annotation.


I am aware that the current solution may introduce surprises because the "flat" serialization is automatically applied to each and every record type that specifies a value field. I may consider adding a @StrongType annotation to make this explicit.
I'd be happy for any feedback.

The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions for guidance on writing good question titles.
